# Regex to extract all urls from string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

> `http://example.com/path/topage.htmlhttp://twitter.com/p/xyanhshttp://httpget.org/get.zipwww.google.com/privacy.htmlhttps://goodurl.net/`

I would like to extract all url / webaddress into a Array. for example

`urls = ['http://example.com/path/topage.html','http://twitter.com/p/xyan',.....]`

Here is my approach which didn't work.

```
import re
strings = "http://example.com/path/topage.htmlhttp://twitter.com/p/xyanhshttp://httpget.org/get.zipwww.google.com/privacy.htmlhttps://goodurl.net/"
links = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', strings)

print links
// result always same as strings
```

Comment: This should helpful to you: http://regex101.com. You can play around with your regex there to see what your problem might be.

Comment: Do you have to keep leading `http(s)`?

Comment: Yes, I will have to @Bahrom

Comment: Your "example" doesn't contain all the urls from the given string, and is also not a dictionary.

Comment: I just edited the question. Sorry for the typo . Thanks

Comment: I think you might want to clarify how you obtained this string, and if possible, is there any way to modify that source?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 , There is no way to modify this. Due to large number of urls I didn't posted full list. However, my problem is I have a page of urls as text from where I will have to extract every single valid url.

Comment: "I have a page of urls as text" -- Right. Where / How did you get that data?

Comment: It was given to me as task. @cricket_007

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your regex pattern is too inclusive. It includes all urls. You can use lookahead by using (?=)

Try this:

```
re.findall("((www\.|http://|https://)(www\.)*.*?(?=(www\.|http://|https://|$)))", strings)
```

Comment: Doesn't capture `www.google.com/privacy.html`, otherwise is okay

Comment: hi @Muchhausen , Thanks it is almost working except `http://httpget.org/get.zipwww.google.com/privacy.html` this url.

Comment: @hayesrobin  Does this work for you? `re.findall("((www\.|http://|https://).*?(?=(www\.|http://|https://|$)))", strings)`. It returns a list of tuples in which every first element is the full url.

Comment: Hi @Munchhausen , it is working great! So far this rules detecting all urls. Except for this kind of url `http://www.helloworld.com/path/file.php` . But I can set condition and get the real url.

Comment: @hayesrobin Ok, fixed it with: `re.findall("((www\.|http://|https://)(www\.)*.*?(?=(www\.|http://|https://|$)))", strings)`. I updated the answer

Comment: Shouldn't that be a raw string?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `http://` is being accepted as a valid part of a url. This is because of this token right here:

```
[$-_@.&+]
```

or more specifically:

```
$-_
```

This matches all characters with the range from `$` to `_`, which includes a lot more characters than you probably intended to do.

You can change this to `[$\-_@.&+]` but this causes problems since now, `/` characters will not match. So add it by using `[$\-_@.&+/]`. However, this will again cause problems since `http://example.com/path/topage.htmlhttp` would be considered a valid match.

The final addition is to add a lookahead to ensure that you are not matching `http://` or `https://`, which just so happens to be the first part of your regex!

```
http[s]?://(?:(?!http[s]?://)[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$\-_@.&+/]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/sF0oM0/1)

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer without getting into much complication:

```
import re
url_list = []

for x in re.split("http://", l):
    url_list.append(re.split("https://",x))

url_list = [item for sublist in url_list for item in sublist]
```

In case you want to append the string `http://` and `https://` back to the urls, do appropriate changes to the code. Hope i convey the idea.

Answer (score 0):

here's mine

```
(r’http[s]?://[a-zA-Z]{3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+')
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.